# Adjusting Nutrient Intake for Energy Intake OR Body Weight OR Both?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, adjustment

***Introduction***

I am analyzing a data set which I am grouping in protein intake quartiles. Before using the protein intake data (in grams), I want to adjust it to avoid potential confounding.

***Problem***

I have seen two main methods for adjusting the nutrient intake before entry in statistical analyses, adjusting for energy intake and adjusting for body weight.
The energy adjusted method I would use is the "nutrient residual model" described by [Willet](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/65/4/1220S/4655744). The body weight adjusted method would simply be Nutrinent Intake / Body Weight.

***What Have I Done***

I have had the belief that the energy adjusted method would be the best solution, and the one I went with initially. But after a presentation at a seminar, I was suggested to group my data in by protein g/kg body weight.

Is there any guidance on which adjustment should be used in this case? And would using both adjustment be a wise choice?

Answer (score 0):

So, not an expert in nutrition here, but this seems like an excellent problem to start with the good old linear regression. This is because instead of taking as heresay whether one model is better than another, we can test this directly. You could do this by:

Model 1:
protein intake = intercept + energy intake

Model 2:
protein intake = intercept + body weight

Model 3:
protein intake = intercept + energy intake + body weight + energy intake  * body weight

So this third model would test if energy intake and body weight are related in a multiplicative fashion. You could then directly compare Model 3 to Model 2 or Model 1 by doing an anova test. This will give you a p-value indicating whether adding that multiplicative term has done anything statistically significant. So to answer your questions, yes you can do both, but that may not be statistically significant, so do these regressions to see what comes out as most significant.

Comment: This approach is useful. But I am seeking an answer for which approach would be biologically sound. As in, would it make sense to adjust for energy intake when i've already adjusted for body weight, or vice versa.